# how can i optimize this dictionaries?

Tags: python

i'm writing a little program that calculate my national social number which is an alphanumeric string. the last charachter of this string is a control value which is calculated based on the position (even or odd) of the prior numbers and letters. so every letter or number has two different values: one in the case it's in the even position and another one in the case it's in a odd position. so i wrote two dict like this:

```
odd = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2 and so on}
even = {'A': 1, 'B': 9, 'C': 13 and so on}
```

so i have two dictionaries with 26 letters and 10 numbers each in order to get this control letter based on the sum of the previous string's charachters. is there a way to write a better code for this part? i'm a totally beginner, thannk you

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"? What is the logic behind the values of the `odd` and `even` dictionaries? Where does the "sum" of the "previous string"'s characters come into play? What is this "previous string"? Please read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953).

Comment: Please provide and example string and expected output based on the sample dictionaries provided.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the numeric values of the characters in your "national social number" depend on whether the character is in an odd or even position, and you want to find the sum of these values from the `odd` and `even` dictionaries? When you say _"write a better code for this part"_, do you mean the part where you define the dictionaries, or the part where you calculate the sum? If it is the latter, please show your own code so we know the baseline for what is _"better"_. See [mre]

Comment: Are you sure `even` values are correct?  Something like `{'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 9, ...}` looks much more sensible.

Comment: @KlasŠ. yes, they are specific values that are pre-calculated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few ways to make your code more efficient and easier to read. One way would be to use a single dictionary to store the values for both even and odd positions, and use a tuple or list to represent the different values. For example:

```
values = {'A': (0, 1), 'B': (1, 9), 'C': (2, 13), ...}
```

Then, when you need to look up the value for a specific character (`char`) and position (`pos`), you can use the `values[char][pos % 2]` to get the correct value.

Another way would be to use a function that returns the value for a given letter/number and position, instead of using a dictionary. This function will be called every time you need to find the value of a character based on the position of that character.
This way, you can reduce the number of variables you need to store and the number of lines of code you need to write.

Comment: Your first solution is a good one. IMO you should remove the "Another way..." part or flesh it out to be a proper solution.

Comment: hi, good idea. but i don't understand the second part. if i write a function, i have to store the values of each odd-even charachter, which are static. otherwise if i have the string "GTRHML33F89U423" how can i found the value of each character (G is odd, T is even etc)?

Comment: @jane12, use `enumerate`

Comment: @KlasŠ. i don't understand how can I use it in this case. Can you make an example?